# Record audio with PortAudio

Tags: c++, audio, audio-recording, portaudio

I was searching through the internet for a library to record voice, for a screen recording program project. I found so many libraries to do that, but I chose to use PortAudio. But there's a lot of modules and the documentation is not well organized. So, how to record audio in C++ using PortAudio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PortAudio is a cross-platform, open-source C language library for real-time audio input and output. The library provides functions that allow your software to acquire and output real-time audio streams from your computer's hardware audio interfaces.
So if you want to record input into an array; Save array to a file; Playback recorded data, here is an [example](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__record_8c_source.html) from the official website of PortAudio.
If you want more example programs demonstrating PortAudio usage, you will not find better than this [page](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/group__examples__src.html).